# Hibernate update a certain value

Tags: java, hibernate, hsqldb

I have coded a method which selects or updates a value if it has a certain identifier:

```
@Transactional
public List<Settings> getSettingsByParameter(String identifier) throws Exception {
    log.info("get resultsList by " + identifier);

    if(identifier.isEmpty()) {
        throw new Exception("Identifier is empty!");
    }

    if(identifier == "today") {
        //update today field
        String query = "UPDATE settings SET value=TODAY() where identifier = '" + identifier + "'";
        em.merge(em.createQuery(query, Settings.class).getSingleResult()); 
    }

    String query = "SELECT p FROM Settings p WHERE identifier = '" + identifier + "'";
    List<Settings> resultList = em.createQuery(query, Settings.class).getResultList(); 

    return resultList;
}
```

However, I am getting an exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: settings is not mapped [UPDATE settings SET value=TODAY() where identifier = 'today']
```

Why and how is this possible using hibernate and hsqldb?

I really appreciate your answer!

Comment: Just curious. `if(identifier == "today") {` is that condition working for you ?

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ yes that is working for me. It basically comes from the service and is injected into my dao. However, hibernate cannot update it with my query.

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate is case-sensitive with class names. Try it with a captial S for the Settings class:

```
String query = "UPDATE Settings SET value=TODAY() where identifier = '" + identifier + "'";
```